# Automated JMeter tests do not always work

Tags: jmeter

I wrote multiple automated JMeter tests. They consist of sending in files to REST endpoints, checking logs and databases. They work fine. I wrote a batch script to run all of them, automatically. However, sometimes they run into errors, and I do not understand why.

Here is the script:

```
@echo off
 for /r %%i in (tests\*) do (CALL jmeter -n -t %%i -l result.txt)

CALL >nul find "failed" result.txt && (
CALL   echo ------Failed.-------
) || (
CALL   echo ------Success!-------
)
CALL pause
```

I check the log, and it's always something about the logs. for example:

> Test failed: text expected to contain /Some text I am testing for/

I am using Response Assertion inside SSH Command, and there is a Constant Timer before the assertions, so there is ample time for the log to react to the sent in files.
When I use GUI or CLI to run a single test case, they work. But running them using the script always results in at least some errors, like the one I quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is obvious: your [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) doesn't produce the expected output.

We cannot tell you why does it happen, you need to figure out the reason yourself.

I would suggest either switching JMeter's .jtl results file to XML format and to include the response data so you could inspect the full response and see what does the SSH Command sampler return.

the relevant changes to the command line will look like:

```
 jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t %%i -l result.txt
```

you will then be able to open the `result.txt` in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and see what was the actual  response of the SSH Command sampler.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)